# Check Visual Studio version and install a newer version using Powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, if-statement, chocolatey

Visual Studio version 15.9.29 is present in a shared location.
I have to write a Powershell script where,

> Current VS version is checked
> If it is less than 15.9.29, then update it to the newer version.
> If VS is not present, install the VS from the shared location.
> Here's the code that needs changes (this code doesn't check version)

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
$CheckFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe"
$FileExists = Test-Path $CheckFile


if($FileExists -eq $True) {
    
Get-Date
New-PSDrive -Name "M" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\asml.com\us\shared\us011110\VDIShare" #-Persist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
    $silentArgs     = "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office update --includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop update --includeRecommended --productKey 8XHNT-G6CTQ-MM78B-94B8W-F3MG7 --passive --norestart --noWeb"
$A = Start-Process -FilePath "M:\vs2017_15.9.29\vs_professional.exe" -ArgumentList $silentArgs -PassThru #-wait; $A.exitcode
Get-Date
}else {
    
Get-Date
New-PSDrive -Name "M" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\asml.com\us\shared\us011110\VDIShare" #-Persist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
    $silentArgs     = "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office --includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --productKey 8XHNT-G6CTQ-MM78B-94B8W-F3MG7 --passive --norestart --noWeb"
$A = Start-Process -FilePath "M:\vs2017_15.9.29\vs_professional.exe" -ArgumentList $silentArgs -PassThru #-wait; $A.exitcode
Get-Date
   //
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Detecting the version of Visual Studio is complicated - e.g. multiple versions (2017 / 2019, etc) and editions (Community, Professional, Enterprise, Build Tools, SQL Server Data Tools, etc) that can be installed side-by-side. The VSSetup PowerShell module is a good place to start with detecting all of this, but it might raise more questions than it answers :-). See https://github.com/microsoft/vssetup.powershell for more info...